# don't load 'initial_data.json' fixture when testing

Tags: django, testing

I'm testing a django app not written by myself, which uses two fixtures: `initial_data.json` and `testing.json`. Both fixtures files contain conflicting data (throwing an integrity error).

For testing, I've specified `TestCase.fixtures = ['testing.json']`, but `initial_data.json` is loaded too.

How can I avoid loading `initial_data.json` (not renaming it) in the testcase?

Comment: Wait... so you're writing tests for an app you didn't write?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from Django Website:

> If you create a fixture named
>   initial_data.[xml/yaml/json], that
>   fixture will be loaded every time you
>   run syncdb. This is extremely
>   convenient, but be careful: remember
>   that the data will be refreshed every
>   time you run syncdb. So don't use
>   initial_data for data you'll want to
>   edit.

So I guess there's no way to say "okay, don't load initial data just this once". Perhaps you could write a short bash script that would rename the file. Otherwise you'd have to dig into the Django code.

More info here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about whether `initial_data.json` is something your app actually needs. It's not hard to "manually" load your production data with `./manage.py loaddata production.json` after running a `syncdb` (how often do you run `syncdb` in production, anyway?), and it would make loading your testing fixture much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have tables with no initial data, this code will help you:

edit tests.py:

```
from django.core import management

class FooTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        management.call_command('flush', interactive=False, load_initial_data=False)
```

this will remove your data and syncdb again without loading initial data.