# Can I test a Django app without having the initial_data fixtures loaded?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

I want to test Django applications with special test data that is different from my initial_data fixtures.
I added a test fixture to my test case, but **Django still loads the `initial_data` fixtures**.

How can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146256/912757), you must choose another name for your normal fixture. `initial_data.[xml/yaml/json]` is always loaded automatically, even if you define another fixture for your tests.

1. Rename your fixture to any other name
2. Use [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) after syncdb each time you need data