# ignoring initial_data in django test

Tags: django, python-unittest

In django fixtures dirs, I have the file `initial_data.json` with some data for database.

in some test, I need a empty database, but when I make

```
python manage.py test
```

the initial_data files are loaded.

How I can ignore the `initial_data.json` in test ?

Comment: Maybe something's changed since 2010, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146213/dont-load-initial-data-json-fixture-when-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not rename them to not be called `initial_data` to avoid the auto-loading during tests and then only load them manually in your dev process when required using `./manage.py loaddata` ?